# Is there an animation-duration limit in Internet Explorer?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, animation

I'm making a funky little countdown timer using CSS keyframe animations. Just as a test, I've set the countdown time to something silly like 372 days in the future. For the "days" counter, this results in an animation-duration of something around 32,000,000 seconds. Chrome handles this fine, but IE10 doesn't seem to like it and sets the duration to 1s instead. It works fine if I drop the time down significantly, so it would definitely appear that there's a cap in IE; the question is, what is this cap?

Comment: MSDN doesn’t specify this (at least I didn’t find anything at a quick glance), but I’d suspect it to be a typical 2^x kind-of value.

Comment: The issue occurs with that kind of value, also. Our thinking here is that it's possibly down to a limitation of 32-bit browsers...